# Use form while a Process() is running

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get the output of a console application to go into a TextBox.

I'm using the following code for opening the Application & Getting the output.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K Console.exe";
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
WriteToLog(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
p.WaitForExit();
```

This successfully opens Console.exe, but it doesnt output to the Log TextBox until AFTER the Console closes.
(WriteToLog() is a function I made by the way.)

I have already tried removing the "p.WaitForExit();" part, but it doesnt change it.

How could I go about doing this? I just want the output to go into the Log without having to close the Console.

Here's my WriteToLog function if you need to know:

```
public void WriteToLog(string value)
{
        Log.Text += value;
}
```

Comment: You could try reading the output data asynchronously via the [`OutputDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived\(v=vs.110\).aspx) event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this and it works.
You can give it a try.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\loop.exe";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }

        void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                label1.Text = e.Data; // runs on UI thread
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Adjust the command line args to suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

`WaitForExit` does exactly what it says; it blocks the executing thread until the process terminates. You're probably looking for the [OutputDataReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event, which you can handle to append output to your logs. Alternatively, call `WaitForExit` on another thread, which I would not recommend.

Comment: Works the same way as before, it waits until the Console is closed before it shows the output in the log...

Comment: @ZyDevs Have you tried listening for the event I mentioned? It should do exactly what you need. `Occurs each time an application writes a line to its redirected StandardOutput stream.`

Comment: @ZyDevs Try this - you shouldn't be calling `WaitForExit`: http://pastebin.com/em21cKkN Let me know if that works. Can't test it as I don't have a compiler at hand.

Comment: Still have an error then when adding it to the log: http://i.imgur.com/d1jvXJ6.png